# Multiple gates for one route, laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:isManager', 'can:isOwner']], function() {
    Route::get('accounts-overview',[\App\Http\Controllers\AccountsOwnerController::class, 'index'])->name('accounts-overview');
    Route::get('accounts-settings',[\App\Http\Controllers\AccountsOwnerController::class, 'edit'])->name('accounts-settings');
    Route::put('update-settings', [\App\Http\Controllers\AccountsOwnerController::class, 'update'])->name('update-settings');
    Route::get('contract-overview', [\App\Http\Controllers\AccountsOwnerController::class, 'contractOverview'])->name('contract-overview');
});
```

How to assign multiple roles for the same routes

Comment: Typically, a gate would be an action rather than a role. I don't think it's possible to have multiple like this.

Comment: if you had roles you would just use a role middleware to check and you would have it setup to check multiple roles .. you seem to be talking about 'abilities' here ... you could write your own 'can' middleware that takes multiple abilites to check

Comment: Yes, I have more about "can". and the question was how could I put two or more "can" in the middleware ...
I tried as in the middleware "auth" how to load more parameters, but for can it doesn't work